# Can i use CreateMapSDDraft in the arcpy.mapping library to set the scale range on tiled services at 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, arcgis-10.1

I know that Esri has exposed many properties to the arcpy lib for publishing services. I need to publish a tiled/cached map service but I need to set the min/max scale when I do that. Can this be accomplished via Python code? I don't see it as a property on the help page of the CreateMapSDDraft script. Is it just not supported or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

These are the basic steps I've taken to create a cached map service using Python:

1. [arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000006q000000) tool creates the service definition draft;
2. [arcpy.server.StageService()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Stage_Service/00540000001r000000/) creates the publishable service definition file;
3. [arcpy.server.UploadServiceDefinition()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00540000001p000000) uploads the SD to the map servers;
4. [arcpy.server.CreateMapServerCache()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005400000004000000) sets the cache parameters, including map scales, for the map service;
5. [arcpy.server.ManageMapServerCacheTiles()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Manage_Map_Server_Cache_Tiles/00540000000p000000/) starts the caching process.

The [arcpy.server.ManageMapServerCacheScales()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00540000000n000000) tool can be used to alter the caching scales but I find it easier to delete and recreate.